# How to show / display "complete" output of variable using str function in R?

Tags: r

I have a very basic question.
I would like to see the structure of my variable using the str function in R.

How do I expand the output of int (see below)? I want to see all observations. Thank you very much.

```
str(Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$Age)
 int [1:1137] 4 2 4 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 ...
```

Comment: Try: `Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$Age` it will print until print limit is reached. A bit pointless to "see" 1137 items. Read about `head, tail, summary, table, cut, is.na` to understand the data.

Comment: Thanks, worked. Yes, it is indeed pointless. actually I want to change this variable into a continuous variable. The histogram of this variable has many gaps between the bars. Is this possible?

Comment: This is already a new question, either edit this post or post as a new question.

Comment: If you wanted to change it from an integer to numeric (AKA continuous): `Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$Age <- as.numeric(Dataset_Complete_ALL_Variables_$Age)` works, since this is an integer now. However, if you are changed a field that is labeled a `factor`, you have to change it to `character` before changing it to `numeric`.